# Run specific script on certain window width

Tags: javascript, html, resize, window-resize

I need to add "disabled" state for  fields classes basing on actual browser width.

Below solution  works great but you need to touch browser width to get it work after page reloads.

```
<script>
$(window).resize(function(){

        if(window.innerWidth < 768) {
            $('.mobile-hidden').prop('disabled', true);
        }
        if(window.innerWidth > 768) {
            $('.mobile-hidden').prop('disabled', false);
        }
});
</script>
```

Is there a possibility to convert this script so that it starts up every time after page reloads only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$(document).ready()` instead of `$(window).resize()`.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        if(window.innerWidth < 768) {
            $('.mobile-hidden').prop('disabled', true);
        }

        if(window.innerWidth > 768) {
            $('.mobile-hidden').prop('disabled', false);
        }
    });
</script>
```

This will only run once when the page is loaded.

If you are not using jQuery, you can use `window.onload` instead.

[Read more about it here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload)

```
<script>
    window.onload = function(){
        if(window.innerWidth < 768) {
            $('.mobile-hidden').prop('disabled', true);
        }

        if(window.innerWidth > 768) {
            $('.mobile-hidden').prop('disabled', false);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Now i see clearly difference.
I will read about it definitely! Big thanks!

Comment: @SzymonSzymański Happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

put this in your header

```
 <script>
     $(window).resize(function(){
     $('.mobile-hidden').prop('disabled', true);
     }
 </script>
```